# Changing the Label images in Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, qt4, label

How to change the label image in Qt when the application is running. I am able to change the image of label by adding an icon resource file to that in the code it self. But I want that user can browse the image & can set it in the label. It can be changed by user. So which class I have to use to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [setPixmap](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop)

You can create a pixmap from a [file](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-4).